# To test if a word is an anagram and output a boolean

Tags: python, return, permutation, predicate, anagram

I am a complete beginner in programming and I am trying to a write code to check if a word is an anagram whose output must be a boolean.
When I run the code, the list of anagrams would include the initially entered word which is the first on the list, i.e. if it is an anagram or just the entered word if it isn't. It then returns the last return value even when it should be False.

```py
def find_anagrams(words):

    from iterools import permutations
    import enchant
    d = enchant.Dict("en_GB")
    
    any_word = ("Enter a word /n")
    inp = any_word
    lettr = (x.lower() for x in inp)
    
    for y in  list(permutations(lettr)):
        z = "" join(y)
        if d.check(z):
            print(z)
            if z == inp: 
               return False
            else:
               return True 

print(find_anagrams("word"))
```

Comment: You are trying to generate anagrams or check if given word is anagram against another given word?4

Comment: I am try to test if a word itself is an anagram  and not necessarily generate its the anagrams. I hope this makes more sense

Comment: if you want last value then you should assign result to variable and use `return` after `for`-loop. But I think you should return True when you find anagram but `return `False` use after `for`-loop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to *ask a question* clearly. I can't understand what the problem is: **what happens** when you run the code? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? Specifically **what don't you understand** about the difference? Also, please note carefully that this is *not a discussion forum*. Your level of experience is not relevant to answering the question (and we would be able to guess anyway, if we cared).

Comment: A word itself cannot be an anagram but a word may be an anagram of another word. That's what anagram means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can check if a word is an anagram of another word in the enchant dictionary:

```
from itertools import permutations
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict("en_GB")

any_word = input("Enter a word \n")
inp = any_word
lettr = [x.lower() for x in inp]
for y in permutations(lettr):
    z = "".join(y)
    if d.check(z) and z != inp:
        print(True)
        break
else:
    print(False)
```

Test run #1:

```
Enter a word 
bat
```

Output:

```
True
```

Test run #2:

```
Enter a word 
good
```

Output:

```
False
```

Comment: Thanks Ann but it prints out a series of "False" then the correct boolean

Answer (score 1):

First, your code has typos:

```
z = "" join(y)
any_word = ("Enter a word /n")
```

probably should be:

```
z = "".join(y)
any_word = ("Enter a word\n")
```

and it has incorrect logic as @AnnZen and @furas point out (+1).  If you want your function to be a predicate that returns `True` or `False`, I would structure your code this way:

```
from itertools import permutations
import enchant

def is_anagram(letters):
    for permutation in permutations(letters.lower()):
        word = "".join(permutation)

        if word == letters:
            continue

        if dictionary.check(word):
            return True

    return False

dictionary = enchant.Dict("en_GB")

any_word = input("Enter a word\n")

print(is_anagram(any_word))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could use *enchant* to get a list of anagrams for a specific word.

```
import enchant
from itertools import permutations

ED = enchant.Dict("en_GB")

def get_anagrams(word):
    wset = {word}
    for wtc in map(''.join, permutations(word)):
        if not wtc in wset and ED.check(wtc):
            wset.add(wtc)
    wset.remove(word)
    return list(wset)

print(get_anagrams('steam'))
```

**Output:**

```
['tames', 'mates', 'meats', 'teams']
```